# Create a UserControl if it is used only once?

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a `Form` with dozens of controls in it. The controls are separated into groups, and each of them has some events. All of the event handlers are in the `Form` code, but I really hate it; my class is way too long.

I thought maybe to create a `UserControl` for each group and have the event handlers in it, but I read everywhere (e.g. [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/CustomVsUserControl.html) and [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/179442/So-what-s-the-difference-between-a-Custom-Control)) that `UserControl`s should be used for **reusability** purposes, and here it is really for separating my code into small, more manageable classes.

So should I separate them

Answer (score 1):

Personally I wouldn't hesitate to use a UserControl if it breaks up the code into easier to maintain smaller classes or logical units.

Comment: Thanks. But would it break the very core purpose of `UserControl`s?

Comment: It may have not been the original intent, but it's sort of like asking should I break up a huge routine into smaller logical units that only get used once each when the purpose of a function/class is re-use.   I really don't see an issue with it and can make some code much easier to use.  Plus when you consider testing, the smaller units can be much easier to test independently.